# ServiceStack can't deserialize json object with quotes in strings to dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack

If json object does not contains quotes, then all is okay. Help pls
Exception:

```
{"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"SerializationException","Message":"Unable to bind to request 'CompanyList'","StackTrace":"   в ServiceStack.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromMap(Object instance, IDictionary`2 keyValuePairs, List`1 ignoredWarningsOnPropertyNames)\r\n   в ServiceStack.Host.RestPath.CreateRequest(String pathInfo, Dictionary`2 queryStringAndFormData, Object fromInstance)\r\n   в ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath, Dictionary`2 requestParams, Object requestDto)\r\n   в ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)\r\n   в ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)","Errors":[{"ErrorCode":"SerializationException","FieldName":"query","Message":"'{\"Unknown\":\"company \\\"Railways\\\"\"}' is an Invalid value for 'query'"}],"Meta":null}}
```

Comment: JSON that doesn't contains quotes isn't valid JSON. Please update your answer to show the full Exception StackTrace and the code you're using to deserialize it.

Answer (score 1):

If json object does not contains quotes, then it is treated as JSV. 
the default format for ServiceStack is JSV not JSON.

use

```
T JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(string value);
```

to parse json string to desired type.